# Shadows not rendering properly in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

[image: red circles around shadow clipping]

In the scene I'm rendering (Cycles Blender 2.83) I'm having weird issues with shadows not fully showing up in the render. This also happens in EEVEE by the way. In the image I have circled some examples of the shadows being clipped weirdly. What is causing this and how can I fix this?

Edit: it appears the issue has something to do with the smoke. When I disable the smoke in the render, the shadows that were being clipped show up fully.

Edit 2: I fixed the issue by increasing the max total and transmission light bounces from 12 to 24.

Comment: Please explain in detail what do you mean by "clipped weirdly" and how do you'd expect them to be.

Comment: Well, as you can see in the image, the shadows that I have circled don't fully show up in the render. Parts of the shadows still show up, but other parts don't. That is what I mean by weirdly clipped.

Comment: I'm sorry Edward, I personally can't see anything *weird*. Please add that comment to your question, ideally along with a minimal example (a blend file with one tree and a bit of smoke or something) and in best case someone else will agree and can help out. Cheers!

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by increasing light bounces. Would you like me to add the picture with the correct shadows so you can see what I was talking about?

Comment: Cool! Suggest to add that as answer and accept it so it's useful for future visitors too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Image with the shadow clipping fixed]In order to fix the shadow clipping, I doubled the max total and transmission light bounces from the default of 12 to 24.

Comment: Can we have the comparison? Cheers

Comment: Oh right, there you go!